# Linux C programming to get Client IP always get 0.0.0.0

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

When i try to get client IP,I always get 0.0.0.0 when program running in CentOS,But when the some code running in Ubuntu,It will get the right IP :127.0.0.1
I don't understand that's why.

Please pardon My English.

Here is the code one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>          /* See NOTES */
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
 #include <arpa/inet.h>
//#include <netinet/ip.h> /* superset of previous */
#define BUF_LEN 1024


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int sockfd=0;
    int bind_ret=0;
    int listen_ret=0;
    int accept_ret=0;
    int read_ret=0;
    int write_ret=0;
    socklen_t addr_len=0;

    char buf[BUF_LEN+1]={0};

    struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
    struct sockaddr_in ser_addr ={
                        .sin_family= AF_INET,/* address family: AF_INET */
                        .sin_port=htons(8888),   /* port in network byte order */
                        .sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1"),  /* internet address */
                        };  
//////////////////socket//////////////////////////////////
    sockfd=socket(AF_INET ,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if (0>sockfd){
        perror("socket");
        return -1;
    }
////////////////////bind/////////////////////////////////
    bind_ret=bind(sockfd, (const struct sockaddr *)&ser_addr,sizeof(ser_addr));
    if(0>bind_ret){
        perror("bind");
        return -1;
    }
//////////////////listen//////////////////////////////////
    listen_ret=listen(sockfd,10);
    if(0>listen_ret){
        perror("listen");
        return -1;
    }
//////////////////accept//////////////////////////////////
    accept_ret=accept(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&client_addr,&addr_len);
    if(0>accept_ret){
        perror("accept");
        return -1;
    }
//////////////////operation_data/////////////////////////////// 
    while(read_ret=read(accept_ret,buf,1024)){      //read data,until no data or error
        if(read_ret<0) {
            perror("Socket read failed");
            return -5;
        }

        printf("receive:%s\n", buf);
        write_ret=write(accept_ret,buf,read_ret);
        if(write_ret!=read_ret){
            perror("write");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    //char *inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr);
    char * ip_add =inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr);
    int port=client_addr.sin_port;

    printf("IP:%s  PORT:%d\n", ip_add,port);
    close(client_addr);
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

And code two:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>          /* See NOTES */
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
 #include <arpa/inet.h>
#define BUF_LEN 1024

int main(int argc,char const **argv){
    int sockfd=0;
    int all_ret=0;
    socklen_t addr_len=0;

    char buf[BUF_LEN+1]={0};


    struct sockaddr_in addr={
                        .sin_family=AF_INET,/* address family: AF_INET */
                        .sin_port=htons(8888),   /* port in network byte order */
                        .sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1"), /* internet address */
                        };
    char * ip_add =inet_ntoa(addr.sin_addr);
    printf("IP:%s \n", ip_add);
//////////////////socket//////////////////////////////////
    sockfd=socket(AF_INET ,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if (0>sockfd){
        perror("socket");
        return -1;
    }
//////////////////connection//////////////////////////////////
    // int connect(int sockfd, const struct sockaddr *addr,socklen_t addrlen);
    addr_len=sizeof(addr);
    all_ret=connect(sockfd, (const struct sockaddr *)&addr,addr_len);
    if (0>all_ret){
        perror("connect");
        return -1;
    }
//////////////////data send//////////////////////////////////
    all_ret=write(sockfd,"test_by_kevin",14);
    if (0>all_ret){
        perror("write");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("write:%d\n",all_ret );
//////////////////data receive//////////////////////////////////
    all_ret=read(sockfd,buf,1024);
    if(all_ret<0){
       perror("Socket read failed");
       return -1;
    }
    printf("%s\n",buf);

    close(sockfd);


}
```

Comment: You do realize that 127.0.0.1 is not your LAN ip address or your WAN ip address right? It is the loopback address on your computer, every single computer has that IP address embedded in them and it is reserved for exactly that use so it can't be used as an ip address to advertise to its neighbours.

Comment: This two programs is running in same PC,So use the loopback address! When they running in CentOS ,will get 0.0.0.0,;When they running in Ubnutu,they program one can get the program two IP is :127.0.0.1          That's my question:why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The server misses to set `addr_len` to the size of `client_addr` before the call to `accept()`.

To fix this add

```
addr_len = sizeof client_addr;
```

before calling `accept()`.